# R - creating new columns with criteria based on other columns?

Tags: r

I have the following structure:

```
df <- head(mtcars[,c("cyl","disp","hp")])
criteria <- data.frame("cyl" = c(3,8), "disp" = c(180,380), "hp" = c(90,120),row.names = c("min","max"))

df
                  cyl disp  hp
Mazda RX4           6  160 110
Mazda RX4 Wag       6  160 110
Datsun 710          4  108  93
Hornet 4 Drive      6  258 110
Hornet Sportabout   8  360 175
Valiant             6  225 105
> criteria
    cyl disp  hp
min   3  180  90
max   8  380 120
```

Now I want to create a new column which first checks the criteria according to the criteria data frame and then calculates a ratio. For example, I want to create a column called "disp/cyl" which should first check that both the disp and cycl columns are within the minimum and maximum according to the criteria column. If that's the case then the calculation should be the ratio disp/cyl. If that is not the case it should just return 0. Similarly I want to do the same with a column called "hp/disp" where it should check the disp and hp meet the min and max, then calulate a ratio of hp/disp else it should just return 0.

Is this possible somehow all in one go? How would I build the criteria?

Comment: Do you want this only for hp/disp or including 'cyl'

Comment: I just want to new column to be added to the original data frame. The original columns should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to create a logical vector based on the  conditions

```
i1 <- Reduce(`&`, Map(function(x, y) (x > y[1] & x < y[2]) & 
   (df$cyl > criteria$cyl[1] & df$cyl < criteria$cyl[2]), df[2:3], criteria[2:3]))
df$disp_cyl[i1] <- df$disp[i1]/df$cyl[i1]
df$hp_cyl[i1] <- df$hp[i1]/df$cyl[i1]
df <- replace(df, is.na(df), 0)
```

---

If the conditions should be separate for both columns, then do

```
df[c('disp_cyl', 'hp_cyl')] <-  Map(function(x, y) 
     x/df$cyl *((x > y[1] & x < y[2]) & 
      (df$cyl > criteria$cyl[1] & df$cyl < criteria$cyl[2])),
            df[2:3], criteria[2:3])
```

Comment: The second piece of code does not seem to run but the first looks to be doing what I expect. Could you please explain the logic here? What are Reduce and Map doing?

Comment: @user33484 sorry a missing `)` `df[c('disp_cyl', 'hp_cyl')] ` fixed it

Comment: @user33484  IN the first case, we are looping through corresponding columns of 'df' and 'criteria' ('disp', 'hp'), create the conditions by comparing the correponding columns of both datasets in `Map`, then `Reduce` the `list` of logical `vectors` into a single one with `&`.  This vector is used for subsetting the columns and do the division.    In the second case, we are doing the logical step separately on each column ('hp/disp`) and do the division.

Comment: Thanks, sorry just still having trouble understanding. How is the loop happening through Map and Reduce? Never came across these functions. I understand the rest of the steps

Comment: @user33484  To understand that, check the output of `Map(function(x, y) x, df[2:3], criteria[2:3])` and `Map(function(x, y) y, df[2:3], criteria[2:3])`. Here, the 'x' will be columns of 'df' 2 & 3 as list elements, and y as that of criteria.  In other words, we compare the similary columns of both datasets

Comment: Thank you ill take a look. Do you know of any more readable way to code this? I understand your way now but eventually will have to pass this on! Thanks again really appreciate the help

Comment: @user33484  It can be done in a more readable way in tidyverse.  But, then you will lose the rownames unless it is created as a column

Comment: the rownames are not a problem - do you have an example?